# UINavigationBar forces title view to center on back

Tags: ios, alignment, uinavigationbar, title, back

I have implemented a custom title view for my navigation bar, containing an image and a label. This view is aligned to the left of the bar, by setting its origin.x to 10 pixels.

So far so good, but when I push a view controller and then go back to the main screen, the title view is centered instead of positioned on the left.

I tried setting its left and back bar button items to nil and its origin.x to 10, but nothing seems to work. I tried both viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear:

```
CGRect frame = self.navigationItem.titleView.frame;
frame.origin.x = 10;
self.navigationItem.titleView.frame = frame;

self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = nil;
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil;
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: frame.origin.x = 10;    try to add this to your viewDidAppear

Comment: ow im sorry. I read it fast and did not notice the last line before the code snippet..

Comment: did you ever find an answer to this? I'm struggling with the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

First off you should set up the navigationItem in viewDidLoad (after calling [super viewDidLoad]) NOT viewWill/DidAppear.

Are you only setting up the navigationItem on the second view controller and not the main vc???

If so you need to set the navigationItem on both, or alternatively in a Base View Controller class which both view controllers should subclass.

Comment: I'm setting up the navigation item on the main view controller, in the viewDidLoad method, after calling [super viewDidLoad]...

Comment: You need it in viewDidLoad for every view controller that uses the custom nav title. Alternatively in a base view controller that your view controllers sub-class